# Optional whitespace in Regex lookbehind

Tags: regex

I try to insert an optional whitespace. Somehow it's not working in the lookbehind.

**Regex**:

```
(?i)(?<=SomeValue\s=').*?(?=')

SomeValue='String2Find'   (matches)
SomeValue ='String2Find'  (not matching but should match)
```

**Demo**:
https://regex101.com/r/u67T1W/2/

Comment: What is your regex platform. If PCRE then `(?i)SomeValue\h*=\h*'\K[^']*(?=')` should work.

Comment: Where do you have optional whitespace in the regexp?

Comment: Updated the example with the error. Platform is C#

Comment: C# supports variable length lookbehind. So  `(?<=SomeValue\s*=\s*')[^']*(?=')` will work fine. Don't test that on regex101 as it doesn't support C# regex.

Comment: All you need is `(?i)SomeValue\s*='([^']*)'` - and get Group 1 value. If you can't modify the code, just use `?` or `*` after `\s`.